# Remove package installed with dpkg and dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, uninstall

I have several versions of libseccomp2:

```
$ apt list -a libseccomp2
Listing... Done
libseccomp2/now 2.5.1-1 armhf [installed,local]
libseccomp2/buster-backports 2.4.4-1~bpo10+1 armhf
libseccomp2/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2.4.3-1ubuntu3.18.04.3 armhf
libseccomp2/bionic 2.3.1-2.1ubuntu4 armhf
```

I need to remove the libseccomp2/now 2.5.1-1 armhf, which I installed with dpkg.
But, whenever I try to remove it with dpkg or apt, it cannot because dependencies:

dpkg:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r libseccomp2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libseccomp2:armhf:
 man-db depends on libseccomp2 (>= 2.1.0).
 apt depends on libseccomp2 (>= 1.0.1).
 systemd depends on libseccomp2 (>= 2.3.1).
 containerd depends on libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.0).
 runc depends on libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.0).
 docker.io depends on libseccomp2 (>= 2.1.0).

dpkg: error processing package libseccomp2:armhf (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libseccomp2:armhf
```

apt:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils colord containerd dbus-user-session docker.io init libnss-systemd libpam-systemd
  libseccomp2 man-db netplan.io network-manager network-manager-pptp nplan policykit-1 runc snapd systemd systemd-sysv
  ubuntu-minimal
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt libseccomp2 (due to apt) init systemd-sysv (due to init)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 22 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I delete the package without removing all the essential packages such as apt?

Comment: Do not mix Debian Buster repositories with Ubuntu Bionic! This may cause unpredictable behavior. As you are already see. If it is Ubuntu, then only these repositories should be listed. If it is Debian then it is offtopic here.

Comment: @N0rbert yes, it is Ubuntu. I'm asking how to fix it since I already screw it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't totally remove `libseccomp2` without breaking you system, because many essential packages depend on it.

But you can switch to another version of it e.g. `2.4.3-1ubuntu3.18.04.3` by running:

```
sudo apt install libseccomp2=2.4.3-1ubuntu3.18.04.3
```

Comment: Disabling *buster-backports* would be good idea too.

Comment: But I do already have multiple versions installed. Installing another one would increase the number of versions already installed, right?

Comment: You don't have multiple versions "installed". You have multiple versions available to be installed.